# How to make a repeating alarm more accurate?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I want to make a repeating alarm notification that will trigger in a specific time in a day. the repeating alarm that i made is firing the alarm well but sometimes its off in its set time. for example a I set an alarm in 6:00 am but after the first trigger the following day it started at 6:15 am so i was wondering if their is a more accurate way of setting an alarm?

here is my code for my repeating alarm

```
       Calendar calendar_dog= Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar_dog.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,7);
                        calendar_dog.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
                        calendar_dog.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), notify_dog.class);
                        PendingIntent dog_intent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        AlarmManager dog_alarm =(AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        dog_alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar_dog.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,dog_intent);
```

and on my reciever

```
  NotificationManager notify_dog=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent dog_intent= new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    dog_intent.setFlags(dog_intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent dog_pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,dog_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder dog_build= new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(dog_pending).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pet)
            .setContentTitle("Pet Guide 101")
            .setContentText("have you feed your Dog?")
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
   notify_dog.notify(100,dog_build.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html):

> As described above, choosing the alarm type is often the first step in creating an alarm. A further distinction is how precise you need your alarm to be. For most apps, setInexactRepeating() is the right choice. When you use this method, Android synchronizes multiple inexact repeating alarms and fires them at the same time. This reduces the drain on the battery.
>
> For the rare app that has rigid time requirements—for example, the alarm needs to fire precisely at 8:30 a.m., and every hour on the hour thereafter—use setRepeating(). But you should avoid using exact alarms if possible.
>
> With setInexactRepeating(), you can't specify a custom interval the way you can with setRepeating(). You have to use one of the interval constants, such as INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_DAY, and so on. See AlarmManager for the complete list.

So, to accomplish what you want, you need to use it like that:

```
dog_alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar_dog.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,dog_intent);
```

Comment: @tyreklGana-an did it work? If yes, please check my solution as accepted.